# Connecting to RavenDb via. username and password

Tags: c#, .net, authentication, ravendb

How can I connect to RavenDb using UserName and Password without using connection string. I want to pass the values in code. I have seen a few examples where the username/pwd are setup in config files but this is not what I am looking for.

This is not a windows user, I just want a plain old ua/pwd challenge, nothing more.

Also how would I add the ravendb user on the server side?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Alwyn,

```
new DocumentStore
{
   Url = "http://your-server:8080",
   DefaultDatabase = "your-db",
   Credentials = new NetworkCredentials("foo", "bar");
}
```